# How can I check how much RAM my C#/WPF application needs?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've developed an C#/WPF application that requires to load hundreds of object models. Now I would like to know how much RAM this consumes. So what is the best way to check this? Can I just use the TaskManager? Or is this not reliable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Task Manager to accurately gauge how much RAM your process consumes, as that number is inaccurately labeled; it's actually the [working set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) of the process.

If you want to see how much RAM your application is consuming, you should take a look at the [.NET memory performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx).

It should be noted that you should not try to optimize for how much RAM you are actually using unless you've actually [identified that you have a performance bottleneck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) is the tool you're looking for. And no, TaskManager is not reliable

Comment: Thanks. Did you use this already and can you explain the difference between memory and held memory of a memory snapshot?